Latex compilation error while running Manim code
I have been scratching my head for so long and trying every remedy possible on the net to help me fix the following error while running few Manim codes.
[08/11/24 22:01:39] ERROR    LaTeX compilation error: LaTeX Error: File `standalone.cls' not   tex_file_writing.py:314
found.
                ERROR    Context of error:                                                 tex_file_writing.py:348
                         -> \documentclass[preview]{standalone}                                                   
                         \usepackage[english]{babel}                                                              
                         \usepackage{amsmath}                                                                     
                         \usepackage{amssymb}                                                                     
                                                                                                                  
                INFO     You do not have package standalone.cls installed.                 tex_file_writing.py:358
                INFO     Install standalone.cls it using your LaTeX package manager, or    tex_file_writing.py:358
                         check for typos.                                                                         
                ERROR    LaTeX compilation error: Emergency stop.                          tex_file_writing.py:314
                                                                                                                  
                ERROR    Context of error:                                                 tex_file_writing.py:348
                         -> \documentclass[preview]{standalone}                                                   
                         \usepackage[english]{babel}                                                              
                         \usepackage{amsmath}                                                                     
                         \usepackage{amssymb}                                                                     
                                                           

Any help would be much appreciated.
I am on Mac M1 with Sonoma installed.
Thank you.
I have already installed MikTex. While everything was fine and I don't know how I broke my system and this error emerged of no where.

General remark: I wouldn't use miktex on a mac. Most users will either use mactex or texlive. They are much better tested and more widely used, so any possible problems will be caught much faster. mactex and texlive also allow to do a complete installation, thus avoiding any problems with missing classes/packages.

That being said, did you check in your miktex console, or whatever this is called in miktex, if standalone is installed? Can you show the .log file so we can see if indeed latex from miktex is used or if you maybe have more than one latex installation?

Thanks for the reply... following your lead I removed MikTex and installed BasicTex as guided on the Manim website. I tried installing Mactex but its size was 4Gb ...now my error has changed.
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/manim/utils/tex_file_writing.py", line 105, in generate_tex_file
tex_dir.mkdir()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/pathlib.py", line 1311, in mkdir
os.mkdir(self, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'media/Tex'.    (These are some last lines)

And like u said to show the log files, please guide me how to get them on my system?

I uninstalled BasicTex too and received the same error...this makes me think that my Manim configuration is unable to see the latex installation...Manim runs fine on those animation where latex is not required but throws me error on the ones where I add Number plane and equations and numberings.

finally I installed 6 GB worth Setup of MacTex and ended up with the same error...

I some how managed to fix it....1)mkdir -p media/Tex
2)
mkdir -p ~/Library/Application\ Support/Manim
3)touch ~/Library/Application\ Support/Manim/manim.cfg  4)nano ~/Library/Application\ Support/Manim/manim.cfg
5) Add the following lines to specify the directories:
[directories]
media_dir = ./media
tex_dir = ./media/Tex
6)chmod -R 755 media/Tex
And then completely removed miktex from system...
